graph editor complication
pretty much new to graph editor , I m trying to create an animation pose to pose first after like 140 frames of the animation , I went to see the animation in Bezier mode on the timeline , the animation looks nice but the only problem I faced is my character is spinning weirdly , I went to graph editor to see which bone is making it , I m just having a hard time finding why the character is spinning and which bone is causing it ? its on first 10 Frames (20 - 30 )I reckon I can fix it once I know what causing it through graph editor but I just cant find it , a quick tip would be very helpful , these are some examples , its hard to notice but anyway ( also some of the frame there are some spinning hand also I just wanted to adjust that by graph editor maybe? )


Blend file for more details:


hello maybe share your file (at least the armature)?

i put it there my friend now

It's the bone called root that rotates -278.601d between frame 20 and 30 that seems to bother you, so you can either remove the keyframes or deactivate the track:

As for changing the Graph Editor curves shape, select the curve (select one vertex and press L to select the whole curve, press ShiftH if you want to hide all the other ones), go into the Key panel and explore the functions Density, Blend and Smooth, or simply remove the vertices with X:


my life saver right there as always , thanks my friend

another quick question moonboots please , the one with the graph editor  when select a bone i can see some zig zags sort of things can i make that just straight with one click? thanks in advance

I've edited, I hop it answers?

amazing  best regard

sorry for bothering again , I just like to learn from you moonboots , idk if i should add a new thread for this , but a question to you friend , after pose to pose , do we actually need or better to animate every frame? so we can get the best result ? best regard for your help

No you don't need, Blender interpolates between the frames, is it your question?
